# How to select tr based on td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to select array of "tr" based on "td" class, once I got the array I want to get array of all tr's custom "data-fid" value.

This what I got,

```
var rows = $("#tableB tr").children(".New.selected") // returns  td, but I want tr
```

Once I got rows, I want to get array of there data-fid values,

```
var selectedValues = rows.attr('data-fid');  // not sure if it will work but i guess this is how i would do it
```

I am trying to google but my luck with finding right wording is just failing badly todya.

```
<table id="tableB" class="dmctable2">
    <tr data-fid="1" Class="selected"><td></td><td></td><td class="New selected"></td></tr>
    <tr data-fid="2"></tr>
    <tr data-fid="3" Class="selected"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector for that.

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

Like this:

```
$("#tableB tr:has(.New.selected)")
```

and to get the data values in array:

```
 $("#tableB tr:has(.New.selected)").map(function(){return $(this).data("fid");}).get();
```

An other alternative which is [faster](http://jsperf.com/has-vs-parent-selector) would be to select the `.New.selected` element and then access to its [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$("#tableB tr .New.selected").parent('tr')
```

Comment: Quick question, would it be better performancewise to use `:has` or `$("#tableB tr .New.selected").parent()` since `has` is not specific to CSS? If you don't know the answer, don't mind, I can make a jsperf.

Comment: Thanks mr. alien 
@CustomizedName: great.glad it helps. :)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: to be honest...i don't know. :/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Except if i've made an error, it turn out `.parent` is faster, and by a lot : http://jsperf.com/has-vs-parent-selector. That's good to know I guess!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: indeed yes . :)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: go ahead and update the answer. will help people refering in future. :)

Comment: Thank you guys for help, @MilindAnantwar can you also help me with this question please as its related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426264/cross-filtering-table-data - since I got ids now, I want to filter another's table rows based on data-fid i just collected :-)

Comment: @CustomizedName:sure . let me have a look at it

Comment: @MilindAnantwar updated as you asked, feel free to correct any grammar/spelling errors.